# How to use Wowza HLS AES-128 by dynamic key

Tags: server, video-streaming, wowza

How to config Wowza Streaming Engine to use HLS-AES128 with dynamic key?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with the Server Side API. There are two callbacks:

- onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyVODChunk
- onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyLiveChunk

Example from the documentation:

```
public void onHTTPCupertinoEncryptionKeyLiveChunk(ILiveStreamPacketizer liveStreamPacketizer, String streamName, CupertinoEncInfo encInfo, long chunkId, int mode)
{
    if (streamName.equals("myStream"))
    {
        encInfo.setEncMethod(CupertinoEncInfo.METHOD_AES_128);
        encInfo.setEncUrl("http://mycompanykeyserver.com/authenticate.aspx");
        encInfo.setEncKeyBytes(BufferUtils.decodeHexString("123456789ABCDEF123456789ABCDEF12"));
        encInfo.setEncIVBytes(BufferUtils.decodeHexString("FEDCBA9876543210FEDCBA9876543210"));
        encInfo.setEncKeyFormatVersion("1");
    }
}
```

Rotation is achieved by changing the key. Note that you shouldn't do this for each segment. You have to change the above example and choose your window.

See: [On-the-fly encryption with Wowza server-side API](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-secure-apple-hls-streaming-using-drm-encryption#api)